# Martingale with parameter

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales

I have a problem with this exercise.

Let $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ be two successions of mutually independent r.v. such that $X_n$ ~ $Bern(1/n^2)$ and $Y_n$ ~ $Exp(1/n^{1/4})$. We also define

$Z_n :=
\begin{cases}
Y_n  & \text{if $X_n=1$} \\[2ex]
-c_n & \text{if $X_n=0$}
\end{cases}$

$S_n := Z_1 + \dots + Z_n$

I'm looking for $c_n$ values ​​for which $S_n$ is a martingale.

My attempt:

$\mathcal{F}_0=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$

$\mathcal{F}_n=\{X_1, \dots, X_n, Y_1, \dots, Y_n\}$, $n \ge 1$

$\mathbb{E}[Y_n] = n^{1/4}$

$\mathbb{E}[Z_n] = \mathbb{E}[Y_n]\dfrac{1}{n^2}+(-c_n)(1-\dfrac{1}{n^2})=\dfrac{1}{n^{7/4}}-c_n(1-\dfrac{1}{n^2})$

$\mathbb{E}[S_n \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}]=\mathbb{E}[S_{n-1} \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}]+\mathbb{E}[Z_n \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}]=S_{n-1}+\mathbb{E}[Z_n]=S_{n-1}$ iff $\mathbb{E}[Z_n]=0$, that is

$c_n = \dfrac{n^{1/4}}{n^2-1}$

Could it be correct?

Comment: It is. You might wish to explain the filtration $(\mathcal F_n)$ you are considering, though.

Comment: You are right. Now I've updated.